# How to use vue router children without <router-view> in the parent?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I want to use `children` of routes specifically for the `router-link-active` class being passed through all components in the path tree. Unfortunately, the child components don't render. I've read that child components require `<router-view>` in the parent component to be rendered.

Is there a way to benefit from the `router-link-active` class in the whole router tree without having to put `<router-view>` into the parent component?

Comment: Provide snippet of your code please.